# A special variable for ansible roles installed?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is there a variable or a method allowing one to list all the roles applied to a group of ansible hosts?
For example:

```
- hosts: webservers
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - nginx
    - php-fpm
  tasks:
    - debug:
      msg: {{ item }} installed
      with_items: ansible_roles
```

or perhaps another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what *applied* means in your question.

The variable `role_names` holds all roles of the current play, so it would be an array: `[nginx, php-fpm]`.

```
- debug:
    msg: {{ item }} installed
  with_items: role_names
```

But these roles not necessarily have been *applied* to the hosts, if you mean by that they have been processed. There is no such thing that will update once a role has been run on a host.

If that is what you're looking for you could implement it yourself with a [callback plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#callbacks). AFAIK there is no callback for starting/completing a role itself. But since the names of the roles are present in the task names you could simply use the `playbook_on_task_start`, extract the role name from the task name and store it in some way. I have not yet looked into callback plugins in Ansible 2 where the API changed, but I expect you have access to the global variable list and can manipulate it.